# How do you find out the different versions of individual PHP modules

Tags: php

When I do `php -m` I get

```
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
sodium
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

I want to find out the versions of different PHP modules.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
php --ri MODULE | grep Version
```

where `MODULE` is the name of the module whose version you want, e.g. `openssl`.

Comment: I'm asking this question since I am solving a big question, https://askubuntu.com/questions/991836/driver-error-while-using-a-third-party-framework-doctrine. I figured out individual modules would be the culprit. By the way how do you update individual modules.

Comment: @RamasamyViswanathan Your php modules should be updated with your package manager. So if you just do the usual `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, you should be fine. That issue doesn't look like it would be solved with module upgrades, however.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `php` command without determining the version it utilize default php installed in Ubuntu. You can change the default PHP with the following command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
```

Then you can use `php -m` to show installed modules.

Comment: I think he's looking to find the versions of various PHP modules as opposed to changing the version of PHP the `php` command invokes.

Answer (score 0):

Below will list all PHP modules and all versions of each module installed when multiple PHP version are installed.

#RHEL/CentOS

```
yum list installed | grep -i php
```

#Fedora 22+

```
dnf list installed | grep -i php
```

#Debian/Ubuntu

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -i php
```